# Is it okay to embed an information link in a plant's name in someone else's question?

Tags: discussion

I came across [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/19421/grow-jasminum-sambac-from-already-growing-plant) question. It has an answer and nobody has asked for a picture, so it appears to be one of many that can elicit good advice without a specific picture.

Because I've never heard of this plant, I did some research. It's a bit unusual and I think there may be other people like me who'd enjoy learning more about it. It's not an identification question, so I don't think it's a case where people would provide links in comments.

In this type of scenario, might it be appropriate to embed a link at the  name of the plant, or would it be rude to do that to someone else's question?

Comment: @Stephie Nice catch! Thanks for the heads-up, and I very much appreciate the vote!  :-))  That was a perfect example of why link-only answers can be troublesome down the road! I found a different page with info about that pretty plant!  Hopefully it will stay put!

Comment: You are welcome! Any reason you didn't choose [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasminum_sambac)? Those sites have a tendency to be around for a while...

Comment: I don't usually use Wikipedia because sometimes there's a lot of information to scroll through before getting to the care of the plant. Some other sites have more pictures of the plant varieties, which can help with identification; and focus more on step-by-step application instructions. On the other hand, Wikipedia's wealth of information is what makes it so great, and it certainly isn't likely to disappear! I replaced the link in that question with Wikipedia, and I'll definitely use it more often!! Thanks for the perspective! :))

Comment: Thanks! The main reasons I use Wikipedia are a) it is fairly persistent, b) has the latin name, which avoids ambiguity (sometimes those change too, but alas...) and c) is "mostly correct" through the internal corrective mechanisms. Besides d) it's somewhat "international" because there are often links to other languages, which is nice if your native language *isn't* English (aehm...). If I feel there are no good pictures or good information, I use other sources. I don't claim Wikipedia as the "ultimate" resource.

Comment: Yikes-I keep forgetting how international we are! I shouldn't expect everyone to read English-only sites. Don't worry, I know you didn't say that to make me feel bad, but it's a good reminder! Sorry about that :)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add the information you found. It's an improvement to that post since it makes it easier for people to find information on that plant. If you were curious enough to go looking for it, chances are that other people will be too (especially if there's a convenient link right there for them to follow).

I wouldn't consider it to be rude at all. Adding links is one of the reasons offered in the help center page on [editing](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/editing):

> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

Also, the site [tour](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tour) that is offered to all new users also has a section dedicated to it: "Improve posts by editing or commenting"

Admittedly, some people don't like having their posts edited by someone else, but that's the way things work on Stack Exchange sites; if they don't want their posts improved with an edit, they had better make sure the posts are perfect before posting! :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that section of the Help Center! A closer look at that particular question revealed some other potentially helpful edits, but I appreciate the clarification that adding a link as the only edit is actually encouraged!